# Variable Names with Node SQLite

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm doing a Node-SQLite exercise. Here's some of the code:

```
const findDogByFur = (length, color) => {
  db.all(
    "SELECT * FROM Dog WHERE fur_length = $furLength AND fur_color = $furColor", 
    {
      $furLength: length,
      $furColor: color
    }, 
    (error, rows) => {
      printQueryResults(rows);
    }
  );
});
```

Where in SQLite.org is the documentation for methods such as all?
Why do some variables have $ in front of them without curly brackets?

Comment: hi, named parameters can be prefixed with :name, @name, and $name - so it's up to you which you prefer.

Comment: It's documented [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback)